# Postgresql: How to copy rows n times (n=value of original column A) and insert "yes" k-times (k=value column B) randomly within the n new rows

Tags: postgresql-9.5

I have a dataset where information about public toilet buildings was collected. Each building (dataset row) can contain several toilets (see example datatable below)

To analyze the data, I need every toilet as a single geometry with an attribute female yes/no broken: yes/no. It's not important for me to know exactly if the female toilet is broken or a male one.

So what I try to do is to copy each row of my dataset n times ( n=value of column total_number_toilets) and insert randomly k times 'yes'( k=value of column female_toilets) in column female_toilets and i times 'yes' (i= value of column broken_toilets) in column broken_toilets in the n new rows. The data type of each column is string although there are numbers inserted at the moment, so it should not be a problem to insert 'yes' instead of a number into the columns of the copied rows.

Why it is not important to know exactly if the female toilet is broken or not is  that I just need a huge sample dataset for an application.

Original row:

```
total_number_toilets | female_toilets  |broken_toilets
---------------------|-----------------|-------------------
           5         |        2        |       1
```

new rows:

```
total_number_toilets | female_toilets  |broken_toilets
---------------------|-----------------|-------------------
           1         |        'yes'    |      'no'
           1         |        'no'     |      'yes'
           1         |        'yes'    |       'no'
           1         |        'no'     |       'no'
           1         |        'no'     |       'no'
```